# Post photo to facebook page c# sdk only visible to user that posted the photo

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Good day,

Having a strange issue with posting a photo to a page, I am able to post the photo with a comment without issue using a scheduled date and time. When I go over to the page's wall firstly I see the photo sitting in the activity log waiting to be posted. Once the time has expired the photo appears on the page's wall and I am able to see and comment on the photo. If I get someone else or go to the page via a non-facebook user the picture is not there. I have also tried logging on as another page admin with the same result.

```
    var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
    var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "first_name,last_name,email,id" });

    string diplaymessage = string.Empty;
    diplaymessage = "Message";

    dynamic accounts = client.Get("me/accounts", new { limit = "25", offset = "0" });

    foreach (dynamic account in accounts.data) {
      if (account.category != "Application") {
        var pageclient = new FacebookClient(account.access_token);
        if (account.id == page.ID) {
          dynamic post = null;

          //if (product.Targeting != null) {
          dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
          parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject {
            ContentType = "image/" + product.Extension,
            FileName = path + filename
          }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(path + filename));
          parameters.message = diplaymessage;
          if (product.DateScheduled < DateTime.Now) {
            parameters.scheduled_publish_time = Facebook.DateTimeConvertor.ToUnixTime(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15));
          } else {
            parameters.scheduled_publish_time = Facebook.DateTimeConvertor.ToUnixTime(product.DateScheduled);
          }
          parameters.published = false;
          try {
            post = pageclient.Post("/" + account.id + "/photos", parameters);

          } catch (Exception ex) {
            //error
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there additional parameters that need to be passed to make it "public" even though when checking the permissions of the photo via facebook they all seem to be public?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a solution to this. There is no concept of 'sandbox mode' anymore, you need to set the application to "live", this ensure any posts made by it become public too, see below screenshot.

[image: Application Settings > Status & Review >]

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Sandbox mode of facebook application. This will help to show the post to other users, not only developers.